# pyqt5, Python setPixmap

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a problem displaying an image in a QLabel. This code returns False :

```
print(icon_famille.isNull())
```

Here's the code that doesn't display anything:

```
        icon_famille = QPixmap('./ico/famille-20.png')
        self.label_nb_familles.setPixmap(icon_famille)
        self.label_nb_familles.setText("Familles : " + self.nombre_familles())
```

Thank you

I've tried other image formats but nothing works

Comment: QLabel shows text ***OR*** images, not both.